# How many matrices with integer eigenvalues are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $m,n \in \mathbb N$. How many $m \times m$ matrices with integer entries from $-n$ to $n$ have the property that all eigenvalues (possibly multiple) are integers?

The following table calculated with PARI shows the values for $m = 2$ and
$n = 1,\dots,20$:

```
1  55

2  317

3  963

4  2301

5  4315

6  7793

7  12047

8  18449

9  26527

10  37325

11  48683

12  66149

13  82547

14  104713

15  131247

16  162297

17  191599

18  233813

19  270939

20  324045
```

For $m = 3$, I only know the values for $n = 1,2$:

```
1 6417  
2 260353  
3 2570569
```

Brute force method is soon not feasible. A formula depending on $m$ and $n$ would be nice.

Comment: How do you get these values? Did you run a brute force algorithm with the condition $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ must has integer solutions? Can you share your algorithm?

Comment: yes, I used brute force using PARI/GP. The source code is : ? for(l=1,3,x=0;y=0;for(a=-l,l,for(b=-l,l,for(c=-l,l,for(d=-l,l,for(e=-l,l,for(f
=-l,l,for(g=-l,l,for(h=-l,l,for(i=-l,l,y=y+1;z=[a,b,c;d,e,f;g,h,i];w=factor(char
poly(z));w=component(w,1);gef=1;for(j=1,length(w),if(poldegree(w[j])>1,gef=0));i
f(gef==1,x=x+1))))))))));print(l," ",x))

Comment: The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=55%2C317%2C963&sort=&language=english&go=Search) doesn't know anything about this sequence, so I have a feeling it's a very tough problem that nobody can currently answer.

Comment: I am not sure if there is an exact formula.  What one can hope for is probably a main term and an error term. I suppose this could be a first step.  Is it possible to get some upper bounds and lower bounds to start with? It would be interesting to reduce modulo p and see what percentage of characteristic polynomials split completely in $\mathbf{F}_p$. Another interesting thing worth looking into is the set of polynomials that occur as characteristic polynomials with all integer roots. On the face of it looks like a really interesting problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C(m,n)$ be the number of matrices with specified properties. Here's a lower bound:

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ matrix with integer entries in the range $-n$ to $+n$ and integer eigenvalues. This means that $\det(\mathbf{B}-\lambda \mathbf{I}_{m-1}) = 0$ only has integer solutions. Consider now the matrix

$ \mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \cdots \\
       0 & B_{11} & B_{12} & \cdots  \\ 
       0 & B_{21} & B_{22} & \cdots  \\ 
       \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
  \end{pmatrix} $

where $|a_k| \leq n$ are also integers. Using the Laplace/cofactor expansion, $\det(\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I}_{m}) = (a_1-\mu) \det(\mathbf{B}-\lambda \mathbf{I}_{m-1})$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are $a_1$ and all eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$. There are $(2n+1)^m$ ways of choosing the $a_k$ and each choice gives a unique $\mathbf{A}$. In conclusion:

$C(m,n) \geq (2n+1)^m C(m-1,n)$

The elements $a_k$ could alternatively have been added as the last row, the first column, or last column. But then it is more tedious to take care of all possible double counting since not quite all $\mathbf{a}$'s and $\mathbf{B}$'s result in a unique $\mathbf{A}$ in this case. I don't think the above bound is very tight, though, so it is probably safe to include a factor of 4 on the RHS of the bound.

PS. I would've made this a comment since it's just a bound, but apparently my rep is too low.